# ¿Se usa hoy día la voz "ambigú"? ¿Con qué sentido?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sustantivos

La voz ***[ambigú](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2HpCI0D)*** se recoge actualmente en el diccionario como sinónimo exacto de *bufé*, siendo estas a su vez las definiciones:

> **[bufé](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6F4n7QS)**
>
> Del fr. *buffet*.
>
> 1. m. Comida compuesta de una diversidad de alimentos fríos y calientes, dispuestos a la vez sobre una o varias mesas, y ofrecidos generalmente en hoteles y actos sociales.
> 2. m. Mesa o conjunto de mesas donde se ofrece el bufé.
> 3. m. En estaciones de ferrocarriles y otros sitios, local para tomar refacción ligera.

La voz *bufé* es muy reciente, incorporada al diccionario en el siglo XX, mientras que *ambigú* ya se recogía en la edición de 1770 del *Autoridades*:

> AMBIGÚ. s.m. Voz Francesa, modernamente introducida, que significa la comida compuesta de majares calientes y frios, con que se cubre de una vez la mesa. Regularmente se sirve á la hora de merendar.

Curiosidad: hasta la edición de 1869 (un siglo más tarde) se seguía diciendo lo de que era una voz "modernamente introducida". El ejemplo primero que encuentro de su uso es el siguiente:

> *Todos los Combidados passaron luego desde el Quarto principal al baxo, en donde con 200. Cubiertos se hallaban dispuestas 6. Mesas, en las que se sirviò un abundante, y magnifico Ambigù, con las mas delicadas Viandas, y un vistoso Dessert, ù Ramillete.*
>
> "Mercurio histórico y político", 10/1751, [página 80](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0012177264&page=80&search=ambigu&lang=es).

El caso es que hace poco recibimos en casa un mensaje del colegio del mayor, diciendo que para la fiesta de fin de curso "necesitamos voluntarios para el ambigú", y que "para ayudar en el ambigú habrá que estar sobre las 20h".

Entiendo pues que la voz *ambigú* se usa aquí con el primer significado de *bufé*: comida diversa servida de una vez ofrecida en actos sociales. Sin embargo, encuentro [otra definición en la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teatro_(arquitectura)#Ambig%C3%BA) en el contexto del vocabulario del teatro:

> Denominación antigua para designar el espacio del bar, cafetería o incluso restaurante para el público.

Resulta que cuando fuimos a Madrid en 2018 al concierto de U2, el sitio donde nos vendían las bebidas dentro del Wizink Center era un ambigú y yo sin saberlo.

En todo caso, entiendo que la voz *ambigú* está cayendo en desuso en favor de *bufé*, a juzgar por [las gráficas de Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buf%C3%A9%2Cbuffet%2Cambig%C3%BA&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cbuf%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbuf%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBuf%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbuffet%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbuffet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBuffet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBUFFET%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cambig%C3%BA%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bambig%C3%BA%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAmbig%C3%BA%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Ambigú]

Así pues, querría preguntar:

- ¿Se usa hoy día la voz *ambigú* de forma generalizada en algún sitio o contexto? ¿Es conocida? ¿O es algo regional de Sevilla o Andalucía?
- En caso afirmativo, ¿con qué significado se usa mayoritariamente? ¿Con el de "bufé libre" o con el de "locales para refrigerios en teatros y similares"?

Comment: A mí siempre me ha evocado el programa de radio [_El Ambigú_](http://www.rtve.es/radio/20080818/ambigu/139192.shtml) que presentó Diego A Manrique en la radio musical Radio 3 durante muchos años.

Comment: Para profundizar en el tema, he preguntado [el origen de la palabra](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/36546/20830) en [French.SE].

Comment: Está en el nombre de restaurantes por toda España: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ambigú+retaurante

Answer (score 2):

**Noroeste de México**

*Ambigú* suele ser una comida que se ofrece a modo de cortesía en el cual se disponen una serie de bocadillos y platillos del cual los participantes pueden disfrutar. Estos son ofrecidos como cortesías para los participantes de algún evento social y suele ofrecerse terminada la reunión.

Por otro lado, un bufé o buffet suele ser un servicio o restaurante en el cual los comensales pueden disponer de una amplia selección de alimentos listos para ser servidos. Suele ser ofrecido en restaurantes y hoteles.

Ejemplos:

> El evento cerrará con un **ambigú** para todos los invitados.
>
> El **buffet** está entre las calles 1ra y 2nda.
>
> El **buffet** estará disponible entre 3 y 4 de la tarde.